# Obfuscation to hide some algorithm

Tags: java, obfuscation

I am working on a java client/server application. Every user must be able to create and modify files (containing some sensitive data) through the client application (marking them with a digital signature) or manually (marking them with a 99.99999% chance wrong signature). The signature does not use client identity, only the content of the file, which mean two distant clients creating the exact same file would end up with two files with the exact same signature).

After doing pros and cons, I ended up thinking about using obfuscation to protect from malicious users than would use reverse-engineering to find the algorithm delivering digital signature for a given file.

But if I've understood it correctly, obfuscation makes code harder to read for human, harder to understand, but my goal is more about hiding the algorithm behind digital signature. Any idea on how to make it:

- **Hard to read?**
- **Hard to find?**

At the moment my idea are:

- Using very random names and some useless treatments
- Putting it in a random class at a random place and using stuff from random places
- Remove comments
- Randomize

Also I'm not sure to understand how compiling and reverse engineering work.

When a code is compiled, I ever thought variables were nicknamed in the "[method area](https://www.quora.com/How-are-variable-names-stored-in-Java)", and that a reverse engineering would give us back a code with variables named a, b, c... etc. But it appears not to be the case and it makes sense now that I think about it, since reflection is possible in java, **am I right on that last part?**

To conclude, I'm not sure to understand how this would prevent user to reverse my code (except for variable names' part).

Comment: "obfuscation to protect from malicious users than would use reverse-engineering to find the algorithm delivering digital signature for a given file" If the algorithm needs to be opaque to be secure, than it's a bad algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean? I meant that I don't want people to understand the way I add signatures to files.

Comment: If you look at *any* good encryption/signature algorithm, almost all of them are well known in the way they work and how they are implemented. It doesn't make them less secure. If one can understand how they can fake a signature just by reading your code, it means you're doing signing wrong. It also means you're baking your own signing algorithm. Unless you know perfectly well what you're doing, you shouldn't do it and use some well-known system instead.

Comment: Ok I'm just strugling to understand how my app will be able to determine that the signature of "a" is equals to some word while a user can't find the same algorithm on the internet to do exactly the same and find the same signature (since I said "The signature does not use client identity, only the content of the file, which mean two distant clients creating the exact same file would end up with two files with the exact same signature", this means I have no private key)? Maybe I'm missing something, I'll have a look at these well-known algorithms.

Comment: Because a signature is supposed to be cryptographically secure. That means that you need a key and a cipher to make it work. If one can derive a signature **without** the key just watching the algorithm, how good a signature scheme can it be?

Comment: About your latest edit to your comment, *users* should have the key, it should not be hardcoded inside your application.

Comment: Ok that's what I had a hard time to understand, so I should just work on how to 1) keep track of every registered user and his associated key 2) make sure noone ever gets access to another user's key out of the owner of the key himself?

Comment: Yes, that would be a way. But without knowing more about your architecture and your requirements it's difficult to suggest a precise way to do this. And it would be OT in here anyway. I suggest you take some time to read about encryption/signature schemes around the net to get a better understanding about what you're trying to do. It's an investment in making yourself a better developer :)

Comment: Yes because correct me if I'm wrong, if a user owns a key, it then wouldn't solve my main concern: signature must reflect if the file was created/modified through the application (valid signature) or manually (wrong signature).

Comment: Why would a signature created outside the application but with a correct key be considered invalid? As I said, this is too broad a subject and I don't have all the necessary information to give an educated answer.

Comment: Because I initially wanted to find a way to say whether or not a file would have been created using MY app or something ELSE, but client-side.

Comment: This may sound a little harsh, but if this is a critical requirement for your application, I'd strongly recommend hiring a specialist in cryptography. Inventing your own solution is nearly always a bad idea; most cryptography relies on public algorithms (so any vulnerabilities are found), and secret keys.

Comment: The problem is he currently wants the client to sign the document, so the client needs to have the secret key somewhere, making it not-so-secret.

Answer (score 1):

> I ended up thinking about using obfuscation to protect from malicious users than would use reverse-engineering to find the algorithm delivering digital signature for a given file.

I think this is misguided for the following reasons.

1. There are a few well-known cryptographic hashing functions that are understood to be sufficiently secure against reverse engineering, given the current "state of the art" in cryptography.  You can read about some of the common ones here:

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

   You can combine a cryptographic hash function with public key encryption to provide digital signatures that are (should be) secure enough for your use-case.  For example:

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm

   There are solid implementations of these technologies available for Java.  There is no need to implement your own.
2. Designing and implementing your own digital signature algorithm is unwise.  Unless you are an expert in the mathematics of cryptography, your algorithm is likely to have weaknesses that you are unaware of.  And you are an expert, you will fully understand the difficulty in creating a strong system.
3. Obfuscation is not an adequate protection against reverse engineering to extract secrets (such as an algorithm) from code.  Indeed, in the case of Java it is little more than a "speed bump" for a skilled hacker.

---

> OK, I'm just struggling to understand how my app will be able to determine that the signature of "a" is equals to some word while a user can't find the same algorithm on the internet to do exactly the same and find the same signature.

You have a point.  If the "text" that you are creating a hash for is known to be very short and/or easy to "guess", then it will be feasible to brute-force its hash, assuming that the algorithm is known.   (For example, Gravatar's approach of using hashes of email addresses for privacy is flawed, because it is not hard to assemble a list of known email addresses, generate their hashes and store them in a database that can be queried.)

However, once you have gotten beyond a few tens of random bytes of data, or a few tens words of text, brute-force (and rainbow table) attacks become impractical. So, you can can start with your document, add an "envelop" with a timestamp, other identifying information, and (if necessary) some random junk to pad out the source text.  Then hash the lot.  The other end merely needs to repeat the process and see if they get the same hash.

(There is more stuff you need to do to create a full digital signature ... but read the link above.)

Comment: I dived into this concept for a couple of hours yesterday, I thought I wouldn't be able to use it my case.

Comment: I wrote "A" as an example but in reality it's far more longer. I think my problem is in fact: how can I make it impossible for a user to get the same digital signature than my app (for an identical input) without using a server? I'm starting to think that it's not possible.

Comment: It's none of my business, probably, but I'm still not sure *why* you don't want users to self-sign their file.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel.  Seriously.  There are well known solutions for this kind of thing.  Use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify your misconceptions about *obfuscation*:

- You don't do it on **your** source code. In the java world, if at all you obfuscate the binary delivery, in other words: your class files. Or to be precise: it is mostly about class file obfuscation, there are commercial tools for [source code](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/JavaObfuscator.html) obfuscation.
- Obfuscation is still used within the Android realm, but "pure" java shops, it is rarely used these days

And most importantly: "security by obscurity" rarely works.

If you are really serious about running your code at the client side (where you have no control over it), it might be better to do that part in native code, and to deliver machine compiled binaries for that part.

Comment: there is also [source code obfuscation](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/JavaObfuscator.html)

Comment: "deliver machine compiled binaries for that part" which won't prevent reversing anyway :) depends on how hard you want to make it. One way to make it very hard is to use a hardware encryption module.

Comment: I initially planned on doing it server-side but it happened to be the not user-friendly at all.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Thanks. I didnt know about that one, updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sure, but reverse engineering obfuscated machine code is quite a different story, compared to bytecode. Afaik.

Comment: @AxelCarré I agree, uploading whole files to your server doesn't sound like a robust approach either.